# cant find .getRange google script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function that takes a spreadsheet and it contents and duplicate into a new one. This is my function:

```js
function executeIt(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dH5Ehdn2sLd0gPLzdq77ntLUWYwbSwh1nxr1vD7FgQc/edit');
  var dataRange = ss.getRange(1, 1, 3, 3);
  var myData = dataRange.getValues();
  var newSS =  SpreadsheetApp.create('Myfile ');
  newSS.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, 3, 3);
  
  Logger.log(newSS.getUrl());
  
}
```

But when i run it, it says an error code with the getRange();

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

As you will see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app), `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(...)` returns a `Spreadsheet`.  `Spreadsheet.getRange(a1Notation)` takes a string representing the a1 notation of your range, not the start and end indices of your data.